How to make Bone that is parented to another bone move on it's own
I'm not the best at wording things but here I go.
I am currently making animations for a video game I am making, it is a first person shooter. The hand is parented to the Magazine bone. when I export the Animation, the hand doesn't move in the same way, It mainly stays in place. Is there a way for me to almost, "Bake" the motion that the Bone has while it is parented in blender into the final export?

We miss informations on how did you build the rig and make the parenting between hand and Magazine, but the usual workflow is to create inside the rig a copy of all bones involved in the deforming and put them into a bone collection named "DEF". Each of theese bones will have a copy transform constraint targeting at the corrispondent mechanism bone (MCH), which can have IK, drivers, parents, constraints that are used in the animation process.
At the end you will select all DEF bones, go to Pose Mode, Pose menu > Animation > Bake action (Only selected, Clear constraints).
In this way you will export a simple rig (Only DEF bones, without any constraint or other mechanism) along with its baked animation, without any issue of compatibility between 3D softwares or game engines.
This procedure can be performed directly by some preferences in the FBX exporter, but I suggest you to do it manually in order to follow all the "Under the hood" path.

